# prototype, require and some error

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, prototype

```
var F15c = function (tailNumber) {
    tailNumber: this.tailNumber
    console.log(this.tailNumber);
}

F15c.prototype = {
    Ammo: {
        gun: 6,
        AMRAAM : 6,
        Sidewinder: 2,
    },
    Fuel: {
        Maintank: 10000,
        ConsumptionPerKM: 2
    },
    RangeLeft : this.Fuel.Maintank/this.Fuel.ConsumptionPerKM
}

module.exports = new F15c();
```

question 1:
what did i do wrong in this line that 'Maintank' is undefined?

```
RangeLeft : this.Fuel.Maintank/this.Fuel.ConsumptionPerKM
```

question 2:
on another script I want to create an instance of F15C with tail number 123
i've done

```
/*script start*/
var f15C=require('./F15C');
var F15 = new f15C(135); //error, F15C is not a constructor
```

so how do I do it right?

Comment: Add `RangeLeft` after you define the prototype: `F15c.prototype.RangeLeft  = F15c.prototype.Fuel.Maintank / F15c.prototype.Fuel.ConsumptionPerKM;`

Comment: Yeah, what @ibrahimmahrir said, you can't define a property that uses another property in the same definition. You'll have to do it _after_ the initial definition.

Comment: so basically the var is reserved to the constructor, 
the prototype content for the initial fields and functions 
and any additional field and funcs that use the values should come afterwards.

did i get it right?

ibrahim mahrir i didnt find in the 'similar questions' a dupe for this question, although its a pretty basic one, can you please refer me to the dupe?

Comment: also, what should i do in the require part?